# Echo'ing form elements via Controller function in Cakephp & Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, cakephp, controller

I have to create a form after a successfull ajax function inside a controller. I've tried many possibilities, but all are failure. I'm posting the controller section

**In Controler**

```
$fields = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #003366 "><tr height="30px" bgcolor="#003366" style="color:#FFFFFF "><td width="10%"><b>Fields</b></td></tr>';  

$fields .= '<td >'.$this->Form->input("DocName",array("type"=>"select","id"=>"DocName","options"=>$arrayFie,"empty"=>"Select "))</td></tr>';

$fields .='</table>';

echo $fields;
```

**In Ajax**

```
var dataString = 'ID='+3;
  $.ajax({
      data:dataString,      
      type:'post',
      url:'<?php echo $this->webroot;?>Admin/get_datas', 
      success:function(msg)
      { 
        document.getElementById('divBodyResult').innerHTML = msg;  

      }
  });
```

Comment: check what is returned by adding  console.log(msg);   in success callback

Comment: Check the generated javascript in your HTML page. Why do you use `'ID='+3`? Try with `{ID: 3}`.

Comment: @Holt , I juz put it for demo. Means ID=3

Comment: @nedstark , There is no response. Because it shows a fatal error as $this->Form->input not defined in controller

Answer (score 1):

The fatal error should give you a hint. What you are doing there is

1. Violating the [**MVC**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html) paradigm .
2. Not possible because helpers (like the form helper) are only available in [**views**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html), not in **[controllers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html)**.

I'd suggest to have a closer look at the docs to get a grasp on the CakePHP basics.

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html**

Comment: So how can we create a form element in controller for the current ajax call?

Comment: @MarvilJoy I might haven't made that clear enough, you simply don't do that, use a view instead!